# vbox.addWidget(widget) does not show widget

Tags: c++, qt

Before my changes, I had several single widgets derived from a `QWidget`:

```
Wid* a = new Wid;
Wid* b = new Wid;

a->show();
b->show();
```

They were shown as expected.
But now I want to show them inside of a third widget, in one of its layouts.

```
Container* container = new Container(); // custom QWidget
```

There I say:

```
container->addLabel(a);
```

where I add the widget to a vertical layout `vBox` inside the Container:

```
void Container::addLabel(Label* lab){
  this->labelList.append(lab);
  vBox.addWidget(lab);
}
```

The problem: The widget `a` suddenly is hidden and does not show inside the Container. For testing, I tried `addWidget(new QLabel("Check"));` that worked. I don't see, what I could be doing wrong here...

EDIT1:
In the Container, this is how I set up the layout:

```
this->setLayout(&mainbox_);
mainbox_.addLayout(&buttonBox_);
mainbox_.addLayout(&vbox_);

// Test if the layout works: The QLabel is shown correctly.
QLabel* check = new QLabel;
check->setText("Dieser Text ist im Layout 'vbox_'.");
vbox_.addWidget(check);
```

Before adding `a`, it has a size of `QSize(650, 279)`.
After the adding, it has a size of `QSize(0, 0)`, even if I call `show()`.

EDIT2:

Solved. It had to do with the size constraints in the ui-file. I changed the constraint of the top-level widget from fixed to preferred and voilà.

Comment: You can try to check what a size() methods returns in your custom widget. If your widget has a zero size it won't be visible. And by the way are you sure you have set Container's layout correctly? Try to use layout()->addWidget(lab) instead of vbox.addWidget(lab);

Comment: Have you tried to use `QWidget::setLayout()`? I mean, `this->setLayout( vBox )`, after `vBox.addWidget( lab );`.

Comment: I made an edit to my post. The size is 0,0 afterwards, even if I use `->layout()->addWidget()`.